# How I connect to Azure Access Panel with a Microsoft Account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD tenant build say it is **footenant**.

Among the users I have an account like this:

*foo@hotmail.com*

This is not an Azure AD account.

I push in it's access panel some applications.

But I absolutely don't understand how I can connect to the tenant's access panel

I log on https://myapps.microsoft.com, but then where do I select the tenant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When user foo@hotmail.com signs in to the Access Panel, the directories that user has access to can be selected from the dropdown box in the upper-right corner of the panel next to the username (see example below).

[image]

Comment: thanks it's working

But is there a security issue here? What prevent me from filling this list with hundreds Azure AD's tenant of a random guy?

I made a try with another account of mie and this scenario seems working pretty well